# Heavy ion collision book

Tags: resource-recommendations, heavy-ion

I would like for some recommendations for books that focuses mainly on heavy ion collisions.

I already read modern particle physics by Mark Thomson but didn't find there anything about that subject.

Answer (score 0):

Jerzy Bartke
Introduction to Relativistic Heavy Ion Physics, it's a good book on the subject and covers the heavy ion collision.